# Position fixed does not work with flexbox

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have two `div`s and the idea is to have one on the far left and the other on the far right. Works, but the `div` on the far left needs to have `position: fixed` and that somehow does not go well with `flexbox`. Then both `div`s overlap.

```html
<div class="flex items-center justify-between">
    <div class="bg-blue-500 p-2 fixed">1</div>
    <div class="bg-red-500 p-12">2</div>
</div>
```

How to give `fixed` on the blue div and still keep them vertically aligned at one on the far left and the other on the far right?

Comment: Of course fixed position does not work with flex. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position): "The element is removed from the normal document flow." Can you explain more of what you're looking for here? How would the elements stay vertically aligned if one has fixed position?

Comment: use justify-end instead of justify-between

Comment: add class  **top-0** **right-0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can add `flex-direction` as `row-reverse;` for the parent div along with `flex items-center justify-between` and for the `fixed` div you have to add the css property `left: 0`;

What will happen is ? when you add `row-reverse` this will align the item from right to left so 2nd div will appear on right side and by adding `left: 0` to first div keeps it on left side only.

**Output**
[image]